# how to store the elements of a document snapshot as objects in a list and retrieve their document ids in a transaction operating on firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Firestore database that contains objects of a user-defined class named "Courses" as its documents. Now I want to read these documents in a transaction as a list together with their document IDs. I can store these documents in a list however I can not figure out how to retrieve the document IDs of these documents. As far as I know, a transaction operating on a Firestore database returns a document snaphot when it reads this database with the get method. I want to extract the document ids of these documents from this document snaphot but I don't know how to do that.

Below is the picture of my database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6T6.png)

Below is the android studio java code for my user defined class "Courses.

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;
 
import java.io.Serializable;
 

public class Courses implements Serializable {
 
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    
    @Exclude
    private String id;
     
   
    private String courseName, courseDescription, courseDuration;
 
    public Courses() {
       
    }
 
    .
    public Courses(String courseName, String courseDescription, String courseDuration) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }
 
    
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
 
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
 
    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }
 
    
    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }
 
    public String getCourseDuration() {
        return courseDuration;
    }
 
    public void setCourseDuration(String courseDuration) {
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }
}
```

I tried the following code in java to store the documents in my firestore database as a list:

DocumentSnapshot doclist = transaction.get(document1);
List courses1 = doclist.toObject(Courses.class);

But I do not know how to get the document ids from the above "courses1" List.

Answer (score 0):

You can get document id using `document.getId()`. You will have to traverse every document in the query, get its document id and save it back in your `courses` data object. Read more about it on firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_6).

```
db.collection("collection-name")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        // map the document to the data class
                        Courses courses = document.toObject(Courses.class);
                        // add document Id to each object
                        courses.setId(document.getId());
                        // add each course to the list
                        coursesList.add(courses);

                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am reading the firestore database in a transaction. So I can not make use of the code you have provided. The transaction returns a documentsnapshot object. I need to know how I can retrieve the document ids of the documents saved in this documentsnaphot.

Answer (score 0):

You can only [run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#runTransaction(com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.Function%3CTResult%3E)) a transaction on a [FirebaseFirestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore) object. Since you didn't share your code, I imagine that it looks like this:

```
DocumentReference docIdRef = db.collection("Courses").document("usk...O18");
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(docIdRef);

        String docId = snapshot.getId();
        transaction.update(docIdRef, "id", docId);

        return null;
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
    }
});
```

The above code will read the "usk...O18" document in a transaction, it will read the document ID inside the transaction and it will update the value of the `id` field. I'm not sure why would you need the document ID, as you already know that ID because it is used when you create the reference that points to that document.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yeah, your answer helped. But I resolved the issue in a different way. Thanks though.